# binding predefined functions to Jquery events

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a working script to apply transformations to SVG so that the image is draggable.
The script works when I use the attributes of the html element.

```
<g id="all" onmousedown="startMove(evt)" onmousemove="moveIt(evt)" onmouseup="endMove(evt)">
```

However I would like to bind the events with Jquery something like below and wonder where I am going wrong with the code below

```
$('svg > g').mousedown(startMove(evt));
$('svg > g').mousemove(moveIt(evt));
$('svg > g').mouseup(endMove(evt));
```

Comment: The event expects a function but you're passing the return value of the function. Functions are objects too, you should pass a reference not execute it. So `el.event(fn)` not `el.event(fn())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('svg > g').mousedown(function(evt){
    //do stuff
});
```

or even

```
$('svg > g').mousedown(startMove);

function startMove(evt){
    //do stuff
}
```

`startMove` references the actual function, while `startMove()` uses it's return value.

Comment: I think the second one only works when you have no arguments to pass to the function

Comment: @PeterSaxton in this case it should work because it is expecting the event as the argument

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to do it like so:

```
$('svg > g').mousedown(function(evt){
    startMove(evt);
});
```